# What is the best way to change a img width - with css output or php?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Im quite new to using Redux Framework for creating a Wordpress options panel.
I have created a option to change the width of a logo img.

But i dont know what would be the best way or practice of the following:

1. Just target the css and output the width.

```css
.logo img {width:/* css output */;}
```

2. Use php to call the option.

```html
    global $redux;

<div class="logo"> 
   
    <img width="<?php echo $redux['logo-dimensions']['width'];" />

</div>
```

I would like to think number 1 is the best.
But what would be the best practice of these, and/or is there a better way than this? Pros/cons?
I would like to understand abit deeper why or why not.

Would appriciate a good answer :)

Comment: who would not appriciate a good answer =)

Comment: Do you have one for me? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case with `<img>`, it is allowed (by HTML5 standards) to use inline width and height attributes, which would probably be more effective for page rendering, considering your css is an external file.

However, if you include some of your inline css to prevent content rendering block and the logo image width is declared, the CSS solution would be equally effective.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! Interesting viewpoint. I see what you mean. The HTML5 standard was new to me. Thanks :) This is how we learn!

Answer (score 0):

I think the below given code will be more efficient for css image output:

```
.logo img {
    background-image:url("/imgPath");
    background-size: 80px 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That i believe is true! :)

But the image will not be printable. So it might not be good if you want the logo to be printable (Most logos should be) :) Thanks for feedback on my post!